# How can I keep my react native screens inside ApolloProvider tag?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo

The documentation explains that I can manage my screens like this:

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
  MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
  SecondScreen: {screen: SecondScreen}
});
```

For Apollo, the docs say I should integrate by placing my root component inside ApolloProvider tag like this:

```
const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <MyRootComponent />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

I'm not understanding how to have both.
Something like this won't work since RootComponent is a constant, but I don't know what else to do:

```
const RootComponent = createStackNavigator({
      MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
      SecondScreen: {screen: SecondScreen}
    });
const App = () => (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <MyRootComponent />
      </ApolloProvider>
    );
```

Otherwise I would have to add ApolloProvider tag on every new screen.

I'm new to react native and I'm finding it difficult to manage those classes and constants.

-- Edit ---

Even after setting the correct name RootComponent, I get this error:
Fixing the component name gives me the error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of ExpoRootComponent.
```

My guess is that RootComponent is a constant, not a React.Component class. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: RootComponent doesnt need to be a class. can you post the code for your MainScreen and SecondScreen component?

Comment: "RootComponent doesnt need to be a class.". That statement made me see the code with different eyes and, disappointingly, the problem is that I wasn't exporting the constant App in the end of the file. Please edit your answer accordingly so I can choose it as the right answer.

Comment: ah yeah.. that would do it. done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the name of your "Screen" component, "RootComponent" name doesn't match the name of the component inside the ApolloProvider.

Try this:

```
const RootComponent = createStackNavigator({
  MainScreen: { screen: MainScreen },
  SecondScreen: {screen: SecondScreen}
}, { initialRouteName: 'MainScreen' });

const App = () => (
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <RootComponent />
  </ApolloProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Edit -

also export your App component and make sure you're rendering it in the render function in your index file.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. I will add an edit to the question and show the error I get.